# After adding request_mem_region my driver fails every first access with "busy" message

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

OK, this is really weird to me. I've got a simulated CAN bus driver, it is a Linux Kernel module. Then I have a test application running in user space which accesses the driver via opening a file descriptor and sending `ioctl()` messages.

Now the CAN bus driver is just something I've been adopting to run on the x86 platform (it was running on our embedded Coldfire system). On the embedded system it had to use `request_mem_region()`/`ioremap()` to get the memory I/O area accessible, I don't **need** to do this, but I want to keep as much of the code common as I can.

Here are some useful defines:

```
#define MCF_MBAR    0x10000000

extern unsigned int Base[];
extern unsigned int can_range[];

  //This is the CAN registers on coldfire, just unused on my x86 desktop
Base[minor] = (MCF_MBAR + 0x1c0000); 
can_range[minor] = 0x180;
```

Then during the init we were doing this:

```
if(NULL == request_mem_region(Base[minor], can_range[minor], "CAN-IO")) {
    return -EBUSY;
}

can_base[minor] = ioremap(Base[minor], can_range[minor]);
```

Now if I understand this correctly... all we're doing here is requesting a reservation of a range of non-assigned memory addresses and, if we're successful, making them accessible by us.

I checked the currently mapped addresses via `cat /proc/iomem`:

```
00000000-0000ffff : reserved
00010000-0009fbff : System RAM
0009fc00-0009ffff : reserved
000a0000-000bffff : Video RAM area
000c0000-000c8fff : Video ROM
000e2000-000e6fff : Adapter ROM
000f0000-000fffff : reserved
000f0000-000fffff : System ROM
00100000-1ffeffff : System RAM
00200000-0071038b : Kernel code
0071038c-00ad8a7f : Kernel data
00b58000-00c52fff : Kernel bss
                          <--  101C0000-101C0180 : This is where I'd be mapping memory
1fff0000-1fffffff : ACPI Tables
e0000000-e0ffffff : 0000:00:02.0
e0000000-e0bfffff : vesafb
f0000000-f001ffff : 0000:00:03.0
f0000000-f001ffff : e1000
f0400000-f07fffff : 0000:00:04.0
f0400000-f07fffff : vboxguest
f0800000-f0803fff : 0000:00:04.0
f0804000-f0804fff : 0000:00:06.0
f0804000-f0804fff : ohci_hcd
f0806000-f0807fff : 0000:00:0d.0
f0806000-f0807fff : ahci
fee00000-fee00fff : Local APIC
fffc0000-ffffffff : reserved
```

It looks like there's nothing useing that memory, so I think I'm OK here. So I load my kernel module, successfully, go to run my test program and it fails, run it again and it works. 
Every 1st time you run it after it's been freshly loaded, it will fail... the 2nd, 3rd, nth time, it will work:

```
mike@linux-4puc:~> ./a.out 
  Starting driver test
  Error 'Device or resource busy' opening CAN device
mike@linux-4puc:~> ./a.out 
  Starting driver test
  We opened successfully
```

Here's part of my very simple userspace program:

```
int fd;
char* dev = "/dev/can0";

printf("Starting driver test\n");

if ((fd = open(dev, O_RDWR)) < 0) {
    printf("Error '%s' opening CAN device", strerror(errno));
    close(fd);
    return -1;
}
```

Any ideas on why this is happening? If I remove the `request_mem_region()` code from my driver everything works, so I think I'm just doing something stupid... but why does it fail in the manner that it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit surprised that this works for you at all.  The `request_mem_region()` is passed a value of `0x101C0000` which is within the physical address range of system RAM, `0x00100000`:`0x1ffeffff`.  I'd guess that the (initial) error return is an indicator that the kernel has already installed this physical memory region into its memory pools.  When the driver error-exits (or when the module unloads) does it try to do the proper clean-up and call `release_mem_region()`, which might enable a successful `request_mem_region()` the next go-around?

Normally you would provide `request_mem_region()` with an address range that is *not* in use (i.e. currently *unknown* to the kernel), because the driver is in the process of making that physical address range "usable" (i.e. declaring a physical address range for mapping to virtual address space).

What happens if instead you use something like

```
#define MCF_MBAR    0x90000000
```

assuming that that physical address space is really unused?

BTW if your driver is calling `release_mem_region()` after its first use, then the driver has a bug.  A driver should only release the resources it has actually acquired.  If `request_mem_region()` returned an error, then the memory resource was never acquired.  Therefore there is no reason to call `release_mem_region()` (and the driver would always get the allocation error during `_init()`).  If you inspect some properly-operating Linux device drivers, you will probably find elaborate error-exit schemes (using `goto` statements) to unwind the allocated resources in the `_init()` routine and validity checks before deallocation in the `_exit()` code.

Comment: Yes that address space is unused and makes this work successfully. I guess I was thinking "load to RAM" so mount this in the RAM's area but that was causing the problem. Do you have a suggestion on finding if an area of memory is free rather than just looping check_mem_region()?

Comment: *"area of memory is free"* - Be careful with phrasing, ie. address space or RAM?  Assignments in phys addr space are usually listed in a HW document.  For 32-bit embedded systems the phys addr space is typically sparsely populated.  The assignments are usually hardwired rather than dynamic, but installation of the HW could be optional.  So probing, typically during boot (e.g. by U-Boot) before the MMU is turned on, can find what has been installed.  A "memory list" of usable RAM is provided to the kernel, so if you want to hijack some RAM, you should edit that list before the kernel starts.